# Абстрактный синглтон

Tags: php, singleton

Есть около тысячи объектов, по каждому из которых необходимо сделать по три запроса в БД, обработать результат и наполнить `data class`'ы.

Само собой напросилось решение с тремя синглтонами, хранящими подготовленные запросы и наследующими от одного абстрактного класса с общими методами.

Родитель:

```
abstract class RequestSingleton
{
    private static $instance;
    private        $stmt;
    /** @var  array */
    private        $params;
    private static $binded = false;

    abstract protected function getSql(): string;

    abstract protected function prepareParamsArray($params): array;

    abstract protected function parse(array $result);

    private function __construct() {
        $this->stmt = SMDBSS::getDb()->prepare($this->getSql());
    }

    private static function getInstance(): self {
        if (self::$instance === null) self::$instance = new static();

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public static function get($params) {
        $instance         = self::getInstance();
        $instance->params = $instance->prepareParamsArray($params);
        if (!self::$binded)
            $instance->bindParams();
        $instance->stmt->execute();

        return $instance->parse($instance->stmt->fetchAll());
    }

    private function bindParams() {
        foreach ($this->params as $key => $value) {
            $this->stmt->bindParam($key, $this->params[ $key ]);
        }
        self::$binded = true;
    }
}
```

Потомок:

```
class CiByIp extends RequestSingleton
{
    protected function getSql(): string {
        return 'SELECT LOGICAL_NAME AS ci FROM DEVICE2M1 WHERE IP_ADDRESS=:ip';
    }

    protected function prepareParamsArray($params): array {
        return ['ip' => $params];
    }

    protected function parse(array $result): string {
        return empty($result) ? '' : $result[0]['ci'];
    }
}
```

И вот что-то похоже я сам себя запутал. `$instance` то для них всех будет одним, тем, который первым создался.

Вопрос к знатокам - что делать!? В том смысле, что делать три отдельных класса с дублированием кучи кода не хочется и запросы подготавливать надо только один раз.

Comment: дак а зачем `self::$instance`  а не `static::$instance`?

Comment: @teran вот где вы были пол часа назад?

Comment: ой, такой говнокодище на работе разбирал, что лучше не спрашивать :D

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Answer (score 1):

Я бы на вашем месте использовал инкапсуляцию, если я все правильно понял (поправьте если что) то вам необходимо сделать 3 разных RequestSingleton...

Если да, то в таком случае можно немного переписать код

```
<?php
/**
*Класс подготовленных запросов
*
*@property ACiByIp $config
*@property array $instance
*@property array $keys
*@property int $keys
*/
class RequestSingleton
{
    private static $instance = [];
    private static $keys = [];
    private static $counter = 0;
    private        $stmt;
    private        $params;
    private $binded = false;
    protected $config;

    protected function getSql(): string{
        return $this->config->getSql();
    }

    protected function prepareParamsArray($params): array{
        return $this->config->prepareParamsArray($params);
    }

    protected  function parse(array $result){
        return $this->config->parse(array $result);
    }

    private function __construct( ACiByIp $obj ) {
        $this->stmt = SMDBSS::getDb()->prepare($this->getSql());
        $this->config = $obj;
    }

    public static function getInstance( ACiByIp $obj ): self {
        $result = array_search ( $obj, self::$keys);
        if( $result !== false ) return self::$instance[ $result ];
        else{
            self::$instance[] = new RequestSingleton( $obj );
            self::$keys[] = $obj;
            ++self::$counter;
        } 
        return self::$instance[ self::$counter ];
    }

    public function get($params) {
        $this->params = $this->prepareParamsArray($params);
        if (!$this->binded)
            $this->bindParams();
        $this->stmt->execute();

        return $this->parse( $this->stmt->fetchAll() );
    }

    private function bindParams() {
        foreach ($this->params as $key => $value) {
            $this->stmt->bindParam($key, $this->params[ $key ]);
        }
        $this->binded = true;
    }
}

abstract class ACiByIp
{
    abstract protected function getSql(): string;
    abstract protected function prepareParamsArray($params): array;
    abstract protected function parse(array $result): string
}
class CiByIp extends ACiByIp
{
    private static $instance;
    public static function init(): self {
        if (self::$instance === null) self::$instance = new CiByIp();
        return self::$instance;
    }
    protected function getSql(): string {
        return 'SELECT LOGICAL_NAME AS ci FROM DEVICE2M1 WHERE IP_ADDRESS=:ip';
    }

    protected function prepareParamsArray($params): array {
        return ['ip' => $params];
    }

    protected function parse(array $result): string {
        return empty($result) ? '' : $result[0]['ci'];
    }
}

//можно бесконечно писать код и экземляры не буду плодиться будут вопросы - пишите в комментариях
RequestSingleton::getInstance(CiByIp::init())->get($params);
```

Comment: Да, вариант имеет право на жизнь, плюс за попытку :) Но все-же решение в комментарии от @teran гораздо более корректный вариант. А так-то я вообще несколько по другому сделал, если не забуду - в понедельник отпишусь.

Comment: @rjhdby, зря отказываетесь. Этот варианты более предпочтителен, если отбросить тот факт, что использовать синглтон не очень красиво. Но в вашем решении тоже синглтон

Comment: @ArchDemon в использовании синглтона нет абсолютно ничего плохого. Как и любой архитектурный прием он имеет свою область применения, надо просто понимать где и как его можно использовать. Этот вариант в данном случае оверинжениринг, так как вместо одношагового наследования создается некое подобие фабрики, которая не особо тут нужна. Но, опять же, на вкус и цвет...